# Bootstrap 4 mobile navbar wont uncollapse

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-4, navbar

The issue is that when visiting my site on a mobile device it is impossible to use the navbar as all the links are hidden and when pressing the button to unhide them nothing happens.
I am using nginx, express, ejs, and bootstrap 4. I've copy pasted the code exactly as it was on the bootstrap 4 documentation page. I have all the required components to make bootstrap work including popper.js, there are no issues in the developer console and all resources are loading fine.
Here is a link to my website https://camelliott.tk

Comment: Please provide your code in your question so we can help to understand why it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you pointed the button to wrong target so it won't load a thing.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Camelliott</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    // Actual Nav Here
  </div>
</nav>
```

In the button, data-target is pointed to "#navbarNav", but later the id of the collapse div is set to "navbarNavAltMarkup". Simply change "navbarNavAltMarkup" to "navbarNav" would fix your problem.